# How to return Box-Plot Parameters from Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I've been at this for the past 5 hours in **Plotly** and cannot get it to work.

I need to get the following figure to return the different quartile points (Q3, Q1) etc as it has a strange algorithm which is not normal!

```
fig = px.box(ndf.Price, orientation='h',template="plotly_dark",points='all')
```

I need all the quartile information it is using to create the box plot, any help welcomed!

```
# ******************* IMPORT ESSENTIAL LIBRARIES *******************

from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

...

filename = "data/data_set_prepared.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
...
fig = px.box(ndf.Price, orientation='h',template="plotly_dark",points='all')

...

app = Dash(__name__, 
external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
meta_tags=[
    {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"},
    ],
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.H1("First Time Buyer Page: Is it a fair price?"),
        html.H2("Houses in " + SEARCH_FULL_POSTCODE.upper() + " over the last year: "),
        dcc.Graph(id="box-graph", figure=fig),
        # dcc.Graph(id="primary-graph", figure=fig),
        # dcc.Graph(id="secondary-graph", figure=fig1),

    ],
    fluid=True,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please add a full example, your snippet code is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot extract that information from a plotly figure object, but I have provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71535315/5327068) to a related question that requires extracting the quantiles manually – you can use the function that I wrote that replicates how plotly calculates quantiles (method #10 as outlined in [this paper](https://jse.amstat.org/v14n3/langford.html)):

```
## calculate quartiles as outlined in the plotly documentation 
def get_percentile(data, p):
    data.sort()
    n = len(data)
    x = n*p + 0.5
    x1, x2 = floor(x), ceil(x)
    y1, y2 = data[x1-1], data[x2-1] # account for zero-indexing
    return round(y1 + ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1))*(y2 - y1), 2)
```